# Cirq: n-qubit GHZ state

Tags: programming, entanglement, circuit-construction, cirq, ghz-state

I am trying to write $n$ party GHZ state but at the end of the day, it seems like bi partite state. I am missing a detail. Here is my code

```
number =6
qubits = cirq.LineQubit.range(number) 
def n_party_GHZ_circuit(qubits)
      GHZ_circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubits[i]),
                           cirq.CNOT(qubits[i], qubits[j]))

GHZ = cirq.final_density_matrix(n_party_GHZ_circuit)
```

I can write it by hand with indexes but suppose that we have 10 qubits and in that case I do not want to write it by hand for all combinations. So I am trying to write a function but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
import cirq
number = 6
qubits = cirq.LineQubit.range(number) 
GHZ_circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubits[0]))
for i in range(number-1):
    C = cirq.Circuit(cirq.CX(qubits[i], qubits[i+1] ) )
    GHZ_circuit = GHZ_circuit + C                     

print(GHZ_circuit)
```

which outputs:

```
0: ───H───@───────────────────
          │
1: ───────X───@───────────────
              │
2: ───────────X───@───────────
                  │
3: ───────────────X───@───────
                      │
4: ───────────────────X───@───
                          │
5: ───────────────────────X───
```

This will produce the state:

[image]

which is what 6 qubit GHZ state you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works for me :) But it could be nice to learn as a function. If someone does not write, I will give you your point.

Comment: It should be CNOT instead of CX???

Comment: Both  `CX` and `CNOT` should work.... did it not work for you? I ran it on mine as `CX` and it works fine.